# Footer image in Excel 2012 using spreadsheetgear

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, spreadsheetgear

Can we add footer image to excel 2012 using spreadsheetgear? I want to add a footer image to be appear when we export data from silverlight

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

While Silverlight is no longer around, SpreadsheetGear 2023 for .NET Framework and also now the .NET 6 products ([SpreadsheetGear Engine for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadsheetGear/) and [SpreadsheetGear for Windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadsheetGear.Windows)) support embedding images in the print header / footer areas.  Example:

```
using SpreadsheetGear;
...

// Create a new workbook and access the first sheet's IPageSetup object.
IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook();
IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveWorksheet;
IPageSetup pageSetup = worksheet.PageSetup;

// Add picture into Left Footer and specify picture code (&G) to render it. 
pageSetup.LeftFooterPicture.Add(@"C:\temp\_trash\_logo_net2.png", 80, 80);
pageSetup.LeftFooter = "&G";
```

Note that if needed, there is an overload of the Add(...) method to pass in a byte array representation of an image instead of a file path.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

SpreadsheetGear does not yet support adding or preserving images in the print header/footer areas.  You can add an image to the main area of a worksheet via the IWorksheet.Shapes.[AddPicture](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.Shapes.IShapes%7EAddPicture.html)(...) method but I understand this may not serve as a good workaround for all scenarios.